# Deactivate/Activate Button and Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table with information imported from a database with an Edit and Deactivate button. I am not concerned with writing any of this information yet to the database. My question is how can I have this deactivate button so that when clicked, it either blurs out the row, grays out the row, etc. When deactivated, I would prefer it to not be able to be edited either besides the Activate button being able to be pressed.

I also want the button to switch to Activate when clicked so that if I want to, I can reactivate the row in the table. And preferably both buttons would have some sort of confirmation that comes up when clicked.

Relative HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="deactivate" name="deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Relative Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deactivate').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.html() === 'Deactivate') {
            $this.html('Activate');
            var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to deactivate this entry?");
            if (result) {
                // Code in order to deativate the row
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You've got a variable scope problem. Your if statement that starts `if ($this.html() ===` is not within the same scope as the `.deactivate` onClick function and will therefore be executed on page load, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: Okay, I have the deactivate button working and the dialog box displaying...now I just need it grayed out if i press deactivate and also on the dialog box, if i press cancel instead of okay, it still shows "activate" even though i technically cancelled it....im going to update my code based on your comments so far

Comment: Graying a table row out is as simple as setting the `opacity` style on the `<tr>` element.

Comment: Do you have some sort of example I can go off or some code to go off of? I have an idea but how would I write the onclick event in order to trigger it?

Comment: You could try `$this.closest('tr').css('opacity', 0.6');`

Comment: That works! Now I am left with being able to activate it and it not being grayed out and also it would be nice to be able to only click the activate button and edit nothing else if it is grayed out